# Chrome Devtools doesn't show `.scss` files contents though source maps are enabled and generated and set properly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Here in [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/edit-styles#edit-sass-less-or-stylus) we read and see that one can edit `.scss` file contens:

[image]

But in real it is not true. I have properly set source maps, but Devtools doesn't show me contents of `.scss` files.

Here is my source maps are set all right, it shows in which `.scss` file styles are assigned:

[image]

But when I do `Ctrl + click` on a style I do not get the content of a file:

[image]

Why? How to enable behavior they write about? I use Chrome Canary `Version 50.0.2653.0 canary (64-bit)`

Comment: This usually means that the content of the source failed to load. Do you  use workspace? Does your server capable of serving sources?